# Android ADT installation in Eclipse

Tags: android, installation, adt, eclipse-3.6

While installing ADT in eclipse helios I am getting a problem shown below:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Traceview 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.0.20100617-0521]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.0.I20100603-1100]
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks to me that you have too many selections in eclipse that somewhat overwrite each other. Try going about installing packages one at a time. I've dealt with this before and really the only answer is to actively select what you install at one time. Try referring to the version numbers to determine which ones to de-select (e.g. 3.6.0I20100603-1100).

I would recommend just selecting `Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100` and un-checking the others.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the root cause of the problem, but I really suggest to use the current Indigo release 3.7.2 instead (and even that will be "old" in two weeks when Eclipse Juno arrives).

Comment: But the initial adt installation used to work evien eclipse Galileo...so while installing the the new adt, I used the fresh eclipse copy then I got this problem...Downloaded the Helios...again the same problem...I dont think Indigo would make a differecne!!!